# Send base64 image to PHP via jquery get. Alternatives

Tags: php, javascript, image, jquery, base64

I have a image encoded in base 64 that I generate with a javascript, and I want to save it to my server via an jquery ajax get. 
I searched for several solutions to do this but none seem to work.. 
I tried Curl, file_put_contents and some variations of them in the PHP side. But as they're not working I'm thinking that the jquery may be aborting it before it gets to the PHP. This because in chrome's network timline that request gets a failed status after 7-10 seconds. 
I did a little research and found out that I can only send 2048 characters by url.

So any ideas of what can I do?
I could generate the image on the server (and that would save me a TON of trouble, but my project manager says that he wants all the processing done via client-side so we save resources). Any ideas will ve more than appreciated.

Comment: Try sending it via POST instead of GET?

Comment: Yes it was that. I feel kinda embarrased haha. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy ,first of all understand that you cant send a long string via http GET method . For sending long string you have to choose http POST method .See a jquery ajax example below ..

```
   $.ajax(
   {
   url : "file.php",
   data : {"string" : data},
   type : "POST",
   dataType: "" //i recommend you to use JSON
   success : function() {},
   error   : function() 
    }
    );
```

Comment: Haha, it was so simple I can't believe it worked xD Thanks. I choose this as the correct answer because of the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using `GET` , There's a limit on the length of a URL. use `POST` if you need to send long string i.e base 64 encrypted.

Comment: Yeah it was that, it's funny.. I was considering everything to be wrong except the type I was using. Thanks.